# error handler not catching error 500 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The following is the function in the handler.php file :

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I have a blade named 500.blade.php in the following path :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sharp\resources\views\errors
```

The following is error 500 that I'm trying to handle (without any handling) :

```
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

If I add the `public function render($request, Exception $exception)` function mentioned above, the if condition will not work, and will show the default error, which is :

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

I'm not sure why the if condition is not receiving the error.

Error 500 :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want all `status code = 500` to go through a specific page, you could do something like this:

```
if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {

        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 500) {
            return response()->view('errors.500' , [], 500);
        }

    }
if ($exception instanceof ErrorException) {
        abort(500);
    }
return parent::render($request, $exception);
```

but your way works well if the error is `instanceof CustomException` only.

Comment: Still same issue. The if condition is ignored. Do I have to restart/refresh anything ?

Comment: It's ignored because the error is not `HttpException`, can you provide me what is the error? I mean it's `ErrorException` or anything else.

Comment: I updated the answer, please tell me what is going to happen.

Comment: Still if condition is ignored

Comment: What is the error displayed when something wrong happened?

Comment: I added the error above. This is the pure error without any handling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201381/discussion-between-eyad-jaabo-and-abdallah-sakre).